# Firestore rule does not permit list operation

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have Firestore rules as such:

```json
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    function ownsData(id) {
      return request.auth.uid == id;
    }
    match /feedpoints/{fid} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /feedpoints/{fid} {
      allow write: if false;
    }
    match /profiles {
      allow list: if false;
      match /{pid} {
        allow read: if isAuthenticated() && request.auth.uid == pid;
      }
      match /subscriptions {
        allow list: if isAuthenticated();
        match /{sid} {
          allow read, write, list: if isAuthenticated() && ownsData(sid);
        }
      }
      match /bookmarks {
        allow list: if isAuthenticated();
        match /{bid} {
          allow read, write, list: if isAuthenticated() && ownsData(bid);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I'd like to do is to be able to list all the documents under `/profiles/{pid}/subscriptions`, but, in my Flutter app, I always get an error saying:

> [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

Another thing that might be related:

> Listen for Query(target=Query(profiles/qguefZV3SjOpf1CGdIJrmufoUBPK/subscriptions order by **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=No matching allow statements, cause=null}

I'm using Firebase Emulator for testing out.

Why do I get permission denied error despite explicitly station `allow list: if isAuthenticated()` under `match /subscriptison`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation,

> When nesting match statements, the path of the inner match statement
> is always relative to the path of the outer match statement.

Therefore, the subscriptions match statement should be inside  `match /{pid}` since it's a **subcollection** inside the **`profiles` collection**.

```
 match /{pid} {
    allow read: if isAuthenticated() && request.auth.uid == pid;
    match /subscriptions {
    allow list: if isAuthenticated();
    match /{sid} {
      allow read, write, list: if isAuthenticated() && ownsData(sid);
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Now I feel dumb to not realize that. Thank you, this was a head-scratcher.